# golang: CGO / clang with sqlite3.c

Tags: sqlite, go, clang, cgo

I would like to compile to arm on osx.
With the following command:
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o foo main.go

But I get:
runtime/cgo
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-thumb'

I use this package: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
I tried the hints: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/106

Thanks for every help :-)

Comment: Do you have an ARM Linux cross compiler tool chain installed?

Comment: As the bug report you linked to says, you will need a C compiler that targets ARM Linux.  While the Go toolchain comes with everything you need to cross compile pure Go code, it doesn't include the tools needed to cross compile the C components of packages that use cgo.

Comment: After hours of reading some stuff about cgo. I find this out to. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As the bug report you linked to says, you will need a C compiler that targets ARM Linux. While the Go toolchain comes with everything you need to cross compile pure Go code, it doesn't include the tools needed to cross compile the C components of packages that use cgo." –  James Henstridge

The result, I compiled it on the arm device (raspberrypi).