# Link SQLite3 on ARM (x86_64 host)

Tags: linux, go, sqlite, arm

I need to cross-compile some Go application so it will run on Raspberry Pi. So far it works pretty good with `GOARCH=arm GOOS=linux`, however for `SQLite3` there's some problem with the imported symbols:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build                          
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: 
SQLiteConn
```

I also tried

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
```

with the same result. I presume I need to get the SQLite3 lib for ARM and put it somewhere so Go compiler can link against it?

Comment: Do you have a C toolchain for arm, and do you have `CGO_ENABLED=1`?

Comment: @JimB I don't think so, how do I use that?

Comment: You can choose the target C compiler with `CC_FOR_TARGET`. See `https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to check out other sqlite drivers mentioned on official [wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLDrivers), say this one [github.com/mxk/go-sqlite](https://github.com/mxk/go-sqlite). Just checked, it perfectly compiles for ARM.

But if you want to use this particular library, there is a Github [issue](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/494) related to this problem. Short answer is that you need to have `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` library and then force compiler to use it somehow like this:

`CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`

Comment: I tried `go-sqlite`, while it builds and runs fine on the host system, when built for ARM and copied to RPi - it fails with `_: sql: unknown driver "sqlite3" (forgotten import?)`

Comment: @jdevelop here is an advice to compile on Raspberry PI itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262389/golang-cgo-clang-with-sqlite3-c?rq=1